# formatting a referenced cell as part of a larger function

Tags: string, date, excel-formula, formatting, concatenation

I'm setting up a backup PO system for my company and as part of that they requested that there is a findable Order Code with the following format: VENDOR-DATE-PROJECT CODE ex. AUTON-120522-14-0337

The vendor and project reference properly using the FILTER function but when I try to reference the date it using TODAY() or referencing another cell which is populated with the date it outputs as the 5 digit number code. How can I format the TODAY() function or the cell reference as part of this larger function?

Here is the specific function I'm using:

```
=FILTER('Vendor List'!C:C,'Vendor List'!B:B=PurchaseOrder!A9) & "-" & G2 & "-" & FILTER('IP''s'!C:C,'IP''s'!B:B='IP''s'!E2)
```

or

```
=FILTER('Vendor List'!C:C,'Vendor List'!B:B=PurchaseOrder!A9) & "-" & TODAY() & "-" & FILTER('IP''s'!C:C,'IP''s'!B:B='IP''s'!E2)
```

I have tried referencing the cell as a string, or converting the date as text but the formatting still doesn't stick and using text doesn't format the date properly in the order code or messes up the actual date cell being referenced.

Comment: Look into the TEXT() function.

Comment: thanks for the help, it took a while for me to figure out why I was getting NAME errors but there was an issue with the custom formatting I was using.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Scott for helping me figure out my issue.

In the end, I had to create a custom formatting code to be able to display the date as desired.

This is how I've done it:

1. open the ctrl-1 window
2. go to the custom format tab
3. enter a new code `"MMDDYY"`
4. in a function, use `TEXT(TODAY(),"MMDDYY")`

Here is the final function:

`=FILTER('Vendor List'!C:C,'Vendor List'!B:B=PurchaseOrder!A9) & "-" & TEXT(TODAY( ),"MMDDYY") & "-" & FILTER('IP''s'!C:C,'IP''s'!B:B='IP''s'!E2)`